# How to tar-gzip a directory and put it in the /tmp

Tags: linux-mint, tar, gzip, tmp

Hey im stuck on a assignment and i dont know how to solve it really because iam quite new with working in linux. I have to place a directory in a tar-ball and zip it using gzip.
At the moment this is my code but it wont work and i dont know what the problem is...

dir=$1

tar -cv/tmp/backupfile.tgz $dir

Comment: Forgot to tell, but i get the error : refusing to write archive contents to terminal (missing -f option)

Comment: Welcome to the site. You can always use the `edit` link to add details or otherwise improve your question - reading the comment section is rather cumbersome, and comments are subject to removal by moderators without notice.

Comment: and when the output says "missing -f option" what does that imply that you might have to do?

Comment: see: `man tar` . A key option is  : `-fFILE` or `-f "FILE"`, which specify the file to be created (or read when extracting). CAREFUL: the filename is whatever is just after the "f", so "f" is usually the last option in a tar command :   `tar -cvzf /tmp/yourtarfile.tgz  /path/to/dir_to_tar`  .  + (almost) always enclose variables in doublequotes to avoid many problems: `dir="$1"`  . or `dir="${1:-arg1_not_specified}"`  (so that tar will say an error about "arg1_not_specified", as it can't find a file with that name to tar). Homework: rewrite this portably, you can't use the z option (gnu only)

Comment: and you need to know if you need to create an archive file with the full /path/to/thatdirectory, or just as seen "from" within thatdirectory ... those are 2 very different archives (and that are extracted from different places)

Comment: pro tip: instead $dir use `"$@"` this will allow you archive multiple directories on need